# How do I remove a string of text inside a div after a br with jquery/javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been trying to remove variable produced pricing (from a generated list) that comes after a `<br>` in each div. Here it is:

```
<div class="p-name">
    <a href="somelink.html" class="TLink">Product Name<br>$1.91</a>
</div>
<div class="p-name">
    <a href="somelink2.html" class="TLink">Product Name2<br>$55.91</a>
</div>
```

I have tried:

```
$('.p-name').nextAll('br').remove();
```

and

```
$(".p-name").nextAll().remove();
```

The price can be anywhere from $0.00 to $40,000.00

Any help? Should I be using Javascript instead?

Comment: Can you wrap what you need to remove in a `<span>` tag? And you are using JavaScript already, you're just using jQuery to make the DOM interaction easier :)

If you have a span tag, you can just select that and remove it. Otherwise you're going to have to select the text fragment.

Comment: Unfortunately not. This is a BigCommerce site and is quite restrictive in customizing output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another alternative is to reset the contents of each `a` by using `substr`

```js
$(".p-name a").each(function() {
  var content = $(this).html();
  $(this).html(content.substr(0,content.indexOf('<br>')));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="p-name">
  <a href="somelink.html" class="TLink">Product Name<br>$1.91</a>
</div>
<div class="p-name">
  <a href="somelink2.html" class="TLink">Product Name2<br>$55.91</a>
</div>
```

Comment: @deppem -  this worked great. Now to figure it out how to make it work with pagination.

Answer (score 2):

Each anchor tag has three childnodes: text + br + text.

To remove the br + tx you can do:

```js
$('.p-name').find('a').each(function(index, element) {
  element.childNodes[1].remove();
  element.childNodes[1].remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="p-name">
    <a href="somelink.html" class="TLink">Product Name<br>$1.91</a>
</div>
<div class="p-name">
    <a href="somelink2.html" class="TLink">Product Name2<br>$55.91</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can target the `<br>` elements, and then any siblings coming after it, and just remove all of it, that way you're not counting textnodes, which can be unreliable

```js
$('.TLink br').each(function(_, el) {
  var els = [];
  while (el = el.nextSibling) els.push(el);
  $(els).remove();
}).remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="p-name">
  <a href="somelink.html" class="TLink">Product Name<br>$1.91</a>
</div>
<div class="p-name">
  <a href="somelink2.html" class="TLink">Product Name2<br>$55.91</a>
</div>
```

Comment: This solution worked except for one thing...  There was an instance where a sale price was entered. It is added after the break but before the price and  in a <strike> tag which added extra elements. Thanks @adeneo. I wish I could vote up everyone who answered.

Comment: @Diggetydog - that is correct, this does not remove elements, but a *"string of text"*, as asked.